# How to improve React Native's performance to generate RSA keys in mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, react-native, rsa

I am using React Native in pure JavaScript (to use Expo) to generate RSA keys for Cryptography. I am using [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#rsa).

When generating keys on the mobile device, it takes an extreme amount of time (~75s) using production mode. I put an [example together here](https://snack.expo.io/H1KB6sjPG).

When running on my desktop computer on Node (with `forge.options.usePureJavaScript` enabled). I get ~3s.

I use this script to calculate the time on my desktop:

```
const forge = require('node-forge');
forge.options.usePureJavaScript = true;
const start = new Date().getTime();
forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair(2048);
console.log("Took", (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);
```

My question is why is React Native so slow to generate RSA keys, and overall having a slow JavaScript engine (which is from the device). What can be done to improve performance?

Comment: have you read the notes in the page you linked to? i.e. `rsa.generateKeyPair({bits: 2048, workers: 2}, function(err, keypair) {
  // keypair.privateKey, keypair.publicKey
});` - or use `workers: -1` *to run a fast core estimator to optimize # of workers* ... It's apparently *RECOMMENDED - can be **significantly faster** than sync -- and will use native APIs if available* ... just a thought - I think "significantly faster" is something you're after

Comment: there's also a note saying that `usePureJavaScript = true;` is also going to make things run slower ... it's like you chose the two options (Pure javascript, and generating the key pair synchronously) guaranteed to make the operation as slow as possible :p

Comment: This doesn't apply to React Native because it doesn't support native APIs or Web Workers.
The `usePureJavaScript = true` was for the Node baseline to make the environments as similar as possible.
I've found this issue saying the same thing as I am with no result: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/542

Comment: try the code in the answer anyway - just to see if there is a difference (with usePureJavaScript true and false) just try the asynchronous version if you haven't already

Comment: Yes, I've tried it all before. The React Native code is *forced* to be pure JS (there's nothing else available). SO was my last resort, and it seems like this is a React Native engine (JavaScriptCore) issue being very slow.

Comment: ok, nevermind - did you try any alternatives as suggested in your issues link? So even the asynchronous version doesn't improve anything (I doubt it would, but ... you never know :p 0

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rsa-native most likely, which is what I wanted to avoid (to keep using Expo/only JS).

Comment: Don't know if it helps any, but have you tried opting into Hermes and see if there are any speedup improvements?

Answer (score 0):

This library implements tweetnacl, but uses expo-random to generate keys natively without ejecting:
https://github.com/rajtatata/react-native-expo-tweet-nacl

This library implements the web-crypto library but also uses expo-random to generate keys natively without ejecting:
https://github.com/kevlened/isomorphic-webcrypto